# running simple web app on docker tomcat container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to deploy my web app to tomcat which running on docker. I have a directory "test" and it has two files:

-docker.compose.yml

-hello.war(when I try to run it in local without docker it is running correcty)

Here is my docker-compose.yml content:

```
  my-test:
    image: tomcat
    ports:
       - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
       - ./hello.war:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/hello.war
```

I am running `docker-compose up` in "test" directory.

Then I am taking this :  `http://paste.ubuntu.com/23108774/`

`docker ps` output:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED                 STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
49bf16c1f366        tomcat              "catalina.sh run"   12 minutes     ago      Up 17 seconds       0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   test_my-test_1
```

I am going to `localhost:8080` then I see only Tomcat Home page.

I didnt understand why my web app is not running on localhost:8080. where I am wrong?

docker version :1.12.1
OS:ubuntu 16.04

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a docker problem. Don't you need to reference the context path to your war file like e.g. `localhost:8080/hello` when you don't run it as ROOT.war?

Comment: how tomcat will know war file without `./hello.war:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/hello.war`. I am very new, how can I run it as ROOT.war?

Comment: AFAIK it should be enough to overwrite the existing ROOT.war by just linking it as ROOT.war into the container (`./hello.war:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war`). Did you check if it works when you go to `localhost:8080/hello`?

Comment: I edit volume like this: `./hello.war:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war` .But didnot not change anything.

Comment: Did you check if the application loads when you go to `/hello` in your former setup? If not, I would check the tomcat logs before trying anything else.

Comment: Do you mean tomcat setup without docker with "former setup"? If it is yes, I checked war file and it is running normally.